# Is there a way to retry restarting a docker container if its port binding fails?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container, docker-network

I am trying to find a way so that a container with host port binding will restart if port mapping fails, just like it does based on healthchecks.

I am using docker-compose to manage multiple docker containers in the same docker network. One of them needs to map a port range with the host. However, sometimes one of the host ports in that range might become temporarily unavailable (e.g., when the host instance is initialized) causing the container to exit. The container remains at Exited state and visible through `docker ps -a`. `docker inspect <container_id>` displays the following error:

```
        "Error": "driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint <container_name> (<container_id>): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:<port>: bind: address already in use",
        "StartedAt": "2022-01-11T15:00:58.90581688Z",
        "FinishedAt": "2022-01-11T15:02:58.00504584Z",
        "Health": {
            "Status": "unhealthy",
            "FailingStreak": 0,
            "Log": [
                {
                    "Start": "2022-01-11T15:01:18.906002309Z",
                    "End": "2022-01-11T15:01:19.193144266Z",
                    "ExitCode": 0,
                    "Output": "7\n"
                },
                {
                    "Start": "2022-01-11T15:01:39.215216028Z",
                    "End": "2022-01-11T15:01:39.269082647Z",
                    "ExitCode": 0,
                    "Output": "7\n"
                },
                {
                    "Start": "2022-01-11T15:01:59.29146919Z",
                    "End": "2022-01-11T15:01:59.355386838Z",
                    "ExitCode": 0,
                    "Output": "7\n"
                },
                {
                    "Start": "2022-01-11T15:02:19.375357304Z",
                    "End": "2022-01-11T15:02:19.420589614Z",
                    "ExitCode": 0,
                    "Output": "7\n"
                },
                {
                    "Start": "2022-01-11T15:02:39.440870926Z",
                    "End": "2022-01-11T15:02:39.502808386Z",
                    "ExitCode": 0,
                    "Output": "7\n"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```

, `container_name`, `container_id` and `port` being self-explanatory.

The issue appears to be temporary and the port is available shortly after the service exits, however there is no retry for it to start. Is there such an option through docker-compose, healthchecks or any other ideas?

- There is a `restart: always` entry on the service's `docker-compose.yml` service entry that works when the container exits during, e.g, a runtime error. This, however, does not seem to apply during this stage of port binding.
- The port range essentially describes a set of suggested ports for the containerized service and not all of them need to be available for it to work, so I could do also with ignoring any non-binded ports.
- Unfortunately, I cannot let docker do the assignment of the host ports.

I am aware that docker does not handle port ranges very good but changing the container network to host (although it might be the best solution overall) would require refactoring in other services and configurations as well, which I am trying to avoid. I would like first to exhaust all options while maintaining the container in its isolated docker network.